# Select data from two tables in SQLAlchemy based on FK

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables.  Table 1's product_id is an FK of Table 2.

In SQLAlchemy, how would I select a particular user_id's product_id from table 1, and also retrieve its product_description from table 2?

```
Table 1
user_id, product_id
1           2
2           5
3           2

Table 2
product_id, product_description
1               some product_description
2               some product_description
3               some product_description
4               some product_description
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q = (session.query(User, Product)
     .outerjoin(User.products)
     )
for u, p in q.all():
    print(u, p)
```